# Wampserver not working after changing PHP versison from 5.6.16 to 7.0.0

Tags: php, windows-10, 64-bit, wampserver, restart

I have Wampserver 3.0.0 installed in my Windows 10 64bit pc. Today, for the first time, I tried to change PHP version in icon tray of wampserver from 5.6.16 to 7.0.0. It automatically tried to restart wampserver as it would usually do but it stopped at yellow icon. Since then I have tried to restart it so many time, tried to stop/start, restart and even restarted my pc but it wont turn wamp icon to green again. I am struck. There is no new error logged in Apache, PHP or MySQL logs after I tried to change PHP version. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Look at the Windows Event log for messages from Apache

Comment: WAMPServer current version is 3.1.0. The **WAMPServer Update** link [on the backup repo here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) will download a upgrade install that will upgrade 3.0.0 to 3.1.0. There are also installs for the latest versions of PHP5.6 and PHP7.0 and PHP7.1 on that page as well